# Animating child element of ngRepeat on the 'enter' event. How can I avoid the animation for data initialization?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

```
// please refer to the jsfiddle link below for the complete code.
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udGjw/1/). Basically, the animation works just the way I want, but I don't want the it to occur for data initialization. What do I do?

I prefer to see a proper way of dealing with this situation, rather than some hack like accessing DOM objects in the angularjs controller.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried using `ngClass` to implment a switch on the animation and I like the simplicity of it. The problem, however, is that this approach somehow works only if [the animation is applies on the element with the `ngRepeat` directive](http://jsfiddle.net/udGjw/2/), but in this particular scenario I need [the animation to occur on *a child element of `ngRepeat`*](http://jsfiddle.net/udGjw/3/).

Comment: As an addendum to @apols' answer, this fades in and out: http://jsfiddle.net/NKa3m/1

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `$watch` to trigger the animation when the data has loaded, here's a basic example using `ng-show`

## HTML

```
<div ng-show="load"></div>
```

## Controller

```
function myCtrl($scope, $timeout) {

$scope.load = true; 

$timeout(function() {
    $scope.users = [
        {name: 'George', age: 20},
        {name: 'Tom', age:21},
        {name: 'Feeling', age:22}
    ];

 $scope.load = false;

}, 1000);

$scope.addRow = function(){
    $scope.users.push({name: 'New user', age: null});
};
```

}

## Directive

```
app.directive( 'afterLoadedAnimation', function() {

return { 

    scope : true,
    link : function ( $scope, element, attributes ){

        $scope.$watch( 'load', function ( newVal, oldVal ){

             if( newVal !== oldVal ){

                 // Trigger the animation

               }

            });
      }
 });
```

Comment: This is a hackish way of doing it. What if you don't know how long it will take to load?

Comment: In my case, I don't know how long it will take to load ( I'm fetching cross-domain data via JSONP ) and I want the animation to trigger after the data has fully loaded.

Comment: @c--misura - Your approach is basically of the same concept as using `ngClass` but with more code. `ngClass` does `$watch` under the hood. For your case, you might want to experiment with `ngClass`. If that works, this directive becomes unnecessary and thus skim down your code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've never really used `ng-class` before, but I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` to set a "new" class that exists only if `user.name == 'New User'`. Then only apply the animation to users with the "new" class. For example:

```
<div class="user-name" style="display:inline-block" ng-class="{new: user.name == 'New user'}">
```

Then in your CSS,

```
.user-entry.ng-enter .new {
    background: #5da423;
}
```

Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/NKa3m/

Comment: apohl: This approach is cleanest that I have tried so far. Unfortunately, it would work if I was animating the element with the `ngRepeat` directive, but in this particular scenario it's a child element that gets animated.

Comment: @tamakisquare I have made edits to my answer that I believe fix your issue, along with a jsfiddle.

Comment: apohl: On the surface, it looks like your update has fixed the problem, but if you take a closer look the animation is not in effect. The background colour does not disappear in a fading fashion but simply being taken away.

Comment: As an addendum to @apols' answer, this fades in and out: http://jsfiddle.net/NKa3m/1/

Comment: @c--misura - It's close but not quite there yet. If you look at the original jsFiddle, the intended animation effect is from a solid background to transparent/none (ie. fade-out, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/udGjw/2/)). Your version gives a fade-in and fade-out animation, instead.